# TemplateSyntaxError during Template rendering

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

Python/Django beginner here - I get this error:

> Reverse for 'topic' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}'
>   not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topics/(?P\d+)/$']

when trying to load my template.
This is my template:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<p>Topics</p>

<ul>
{% for topic in topics %}
  <li>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic_id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
  </li>
{% empty %}
  <li>No topics for now</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Topic

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    '''Home page for learning log'''
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

def topics(request):
    '''Show all topics'''
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

def topic(request, topic_id):
    '''Show a single topic and all its entries'''
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

I have been on this a while now, read some previous answers here, but they all had to do with auth/login not working. Also tried removing the '' after the url as some answers suggested but it didnt work. I am using **Python Crash Course: A Hands-On, Project-Based Introduction to Programming** for my tutorials.

Any help will be appreciated.

Finally, this is my urls.py code
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),  
    url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'), 
    url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topics, name='topic'),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error, there was an argument passed into the `url` tag, but it was empty:

> Reverse for 'topic' with arguments **'('',)'**...

That's because of the `topic_id` variable, it is not defined. You should use `topic.id` instead:

```
<a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
```

Comment: @Alezandah you should accept this answer by clicking the check symbol to show that your problem is solved... and to thank alex for this effort ;)